# html "selected" does not work with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a piece of code where users get car model based on car make with Ajax. It works well. However, when the user enters to "edit car" page the make of the car is selected automatically, but, the model not.

[image]

How can I fix it? Here is my ajax file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="make"]').on('change', function() {
            var makeid = $(this).val();
            if(makeid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + 'myform/ajax/'+makeid,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="model"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="model"]').append('<option value="'+ value.id +'">'+ value.modeltitle +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="model"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Show the response you get from server.

Comment: You have to send car model id with ajax at the time of edit.. Show your edit data.. maybe I can solve it...

Comment: @GyandeepSharma you mean html?

Comment: html plus data array you fetched from  database for edit...

Answer (score 1):

`change` event does not fire when the selection is made/changed through code. You will have to trigger it yourself after you select the make "automatically".

```
$('select[name="make"]').val(<some make>).change();
```

Comment: @JavidAbbasov if you want help, you will have to do better than "it did not work"